# How to certificate alexa custom task with a provided own backend?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-interaction-model

I have an alexa skill that I am developing a custom task for.

The Alexa documentation shows how to send the task definition and input files when it comes to a lambda backend, but I'm using `ask-sdk-express-adapter` to run my own backend.

In this case, how do I send the task definition files and inputs?

I want to certify my skill with custom tasks and test it.